# RadioButton not displaying bullet when item is checked

Tags: c#, wpf

My WPF dialog has a couple of `RadioButtons` in it:

```
<RadioButton Content="Mode 1"
             Grid.Column="1"
             GroupName="Modes"
             IsChecked="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ModeConverter}, ConverterParameter=Mode1, Path=Mode}"
             Margin="5"
             TabIndex="8"
             VerticalAlignment="Center" />
<RadioButton Content="Mode 2"
             Grid.Column="3"
             GroupName="Modes"
             IsChecked="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ModeConverter}, ConverterParameter=Mode2, Path=Mode}"
             Margin="5"
             TabIndex="8"
             VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

I also have the following custom style for `RadioButtons` in my App.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F4F4F4" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource CheckBoxStroke}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent">
                    <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <Themes:BulletChrome BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}" IsRound="true" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" Width="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" Height="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" />
                    </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                </BulletDecorator>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource CheckRadioFocusVisual}" />
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,0,0,0" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Just for completeness sake, here's the code for the IValueConverter I'm using in the IsChecked bindings:

```
[ValueConversion( typeof( Enum ), typeof( bool ))]
public class EnumToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter {

    public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture ) {
        return value == null ? Binding.DoNothing : value.Equals( parameter );
    }

    public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture ) {
        return value.Equals( true ) ? parameter : Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

The `RadioButtons` render as I wish, but they do not have anything checked off, even though the property behind them in the view model object is set.  Clicking on one of the buttons changes the value of the property, but they still do not appear checked.

Anybody got any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think your issue is that you have the <ContentPresenter/> in the <BulletDecorator/> place that right after. You might want to make a <StackPanel> or <Grid> to contain them.

Comment: I assume your view model implements INotifyPropertyChanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is in your converter where you are checking for equality:

```
value.Equals( parameter ); <-- HERE
```

value is of type Enum and parameter will be of type string.

[**Object.Equals**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx) compare references unless overridden in derived class and provide custom comparer. So, in your case ***enum and string obviously are different references which always evaluate out to be false. Hence, radio button is never checked.***

You can do equality check like this:

```
value.ToString().Equals( parameter );
```

This will work because ***string override Equals method to compare values.*** So, it will evaluate out to be true if contents are same.

---

Change:

```
public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                       CultureInfo culture ) {
    return value == null ? Binding.DoNothing :
                           value.ToString().Equals( parameter );
}
```

Comment: I spent a few minutes trying to convert `parameter` from a string into the proper `Enum` type, but the code started getting too hairy & overly complicated.  Your solution is the simplest one that works.